# How to find separated space is between rows and columns in c

Tags: c, arrays

First get 2 int for height and width of a piece of paper for example and the u draw straight lines (first you get the nummber of lines and then you get coordinates) and i have to calculate how many spaces there are (which are divided by these lines).My code so far it's like that can someone help me how can i fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

First you get the count of blocks (size = width * height) then  you can refer this( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm )and create your own algo to calculate devided blocks and add that amount to the size. 
You need to consider the blocka where eventhough the line goes on the block but doesn't divides ( may the line goes on the border )